# No sound on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

Just bluetooth device works.

Can anyone help me with this?
I'm using a MBP13 2017 (no touchbar). The system is updated and restarted several times.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The crowbar method is to reinstall macOS by booting with cmd+R pressed and selecting reinstall macOS. This will install the original version of the OS (and it's audio drivers) without deleting your personal data. Nevertheless I would always do a backup first.

Comment: I would start by checking the audio port for any dust etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Shut down the computer
Press Start and after 2-3sec press Command + Option + P + R

Here is where I found the solution:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iV3WkrRjn5w&t=118s)